# Would a servlet that uses URL rewriting return the session ID in the header or the body?

Tags: session, servlets, url-rewriting

If a new visitor sends a request to the URL of a servlet that uses URL rewriting, would the servlet response  contain the session ID in the HTTP header or in URL’s written to the body of the response? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body, if it contains links because URL rewriting updates the links in a page to include the session ID.

It is also possible if the container does not yet know if the client supports cookies that it could also send a session cookie (i.e. a header) that contained the session ID. Once the client has sent a request with the URL embedded in the URL, the container should no longer send cookies.